# Schedule assistant

Tags: project-management, time-management, calendar

I want a regular time tracker with a schedule, like a Google calendar.

But with some special features:

- I wanna will able to specify when I do or can do a task:

  - strictly, for instance, "work from 9:00 to 18:00"
  - flexible, for instance, "gym for 1 hour from 18:00 to 21:00"
- I also want to specify when and how to repeat the task, and how it is done in google calendar.
- And the main thing, I want some automation, for example, I specify that I go to a gym at 18:00, but if I work overtime, I want to the app to say that today I have worked to 19:00, and move gym to 20:00, or another day.

App will be able to work with one-time tasks, like "write a letter to Santa Claus" that I should do the week before Christmas. And automatically insert it into my schedule

It's also very cool if I can specify the priority of tasks

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I found is [Motion](https://www.usemotion.com/). But it's more like a relatively high-priced enterprise solution ($34/month) because it includes more than just a calendar. But on the other hand it uses AI and maybe it will be better than the manual rules I wanted.